# Adding a row to the end of an Excel Table (List) without selecting the last row first with a command button

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I need to Add a new row to the end of an Excel Table without selecting the last row first with a command button using excel 2013

My table is named: Ledger
Commandbutton1 is named: Add New

I have failed in writing the code, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write some code to determine where the table is and create a `Range` object contained in the table.  It can be any range within the table. If the table happens to be at the top left of the spreadsheet, you can just use A1.

```
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
```

Then to insert the row, get the `ListObject` for the cell, which essentially gets you the table.  Then just call `ListRows.Add`.

```
r.ListObject.ListRows.Add
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this...

```
Private Sub AddNew_Click()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Ledger")
tbl.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
End Sub
```